# "Dismiss" button bug for topic-requests without description

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, documentation-proposals

Here is how it look in Firefox 48.0.1:

[image]

For each topic-request which has no description (when right after title goes requester info), border does not hover *Dismiss* button.

But when topic-request contains at least one line of description - everything looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing `min-height` for that case - will be fixed in the next build.